# Conditional logic and Advanced custom fields that have default content

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields to display content from a url. The fields have default content in them (the url I mentioned). I am using conditional logic on a radio button that has the ID ("nearestCity") when New York is selected it displays the field that holds the New York url. The problem is since the "field ids" are different the content doesn't display so I wanted to write a conditional statement that re-defines the variable when "New York" is selected.

I've tried using the same IDs and writing an IF statement but both just break the page

```
<?php
$propertiesCity = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'propertiescityname', true);
$msa = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'propertiesmsa', true);
?>
```

```
<?php 
/*code for adding nearest new york city*/

$newYorkSelect = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nearest_city', true);

if ($newYorkSelect == "new york") { ?>

<? 
    $propertiesCity = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'propertiescityname-new-york', true);
    $msa = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'propertiesmsa-new-york', true); 
?>

<?php 

} else { 
// do nothing; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish and what the error is/errors are that you're getting?

Comment: @Philip This is a custom template in WordPress that displays info about different cities. The field in question basically pulls data from a database by looking and the value in the advanced custom field. Since most of the users of this template don't know the value to enter in the field to display the data from the database, I created a field within ACF that has a ”needed value” defaulted. If the radio button ”New York” is selected the default value is switched to correspond with the ”needed value” for new york. Since the IDs for these values are different the New York data does not display

Comment: @Philip My first thought was to keep the IDs for the fields ”propertycityname” but that didn't work out when radio button was clicked neither data sets displayed. So my second idea was to swap out the actual variables in the template when the radio button selection is made. For some reason the code that I wrote above breaks the template altogether. I just want to know if there is an issue with the IF Statement I wrote

Comment: The `get_post_meta` gets the value of the custom field that is saved for that post. If it is not present, it returns `null`, if present it will be the value of the radio buttons `value` attribute.[WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) From the code example you've provided, I can't see what's going wrong here. Could you create a full example?

Comment: @Philip Are you saying that the get_post_meta is returned both of the values in the radio button, no matter which one is selected?

Comment: It returns the value or values that are stored in the db. So depending on what is stored on saving the post, that is returned. (Usually only the selected value, but I can't see that without a full example.)

Comment: use get_field('field', $post->ID) or the_field('field', $post->ID) to get the values instead of looking through post meta? You need to better explain what you achieve, are you trying to update post meta for a none acf field etc?